# Journey Builder SMS Send Opt In Behavior

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, sendsmsactivity

In Journey Builder you can send SMS activities to Subscribers, dependant "Delivery Options" you can decide which users get the SMS.

[image: Delivery Option Screen]

In my journey I have selected the later option (Subscribe all contacts to a keyword) which *should* force the contact to Subscribe to the KEYWORD attached to the message selected.

I want to know how this function works? as I have injected Subscribers into this journey who are currently Opt-ed out of the keyword used and don't receive the SMS when they pass the activity.

Comment: This is a good question - I'm currently also trying to figure out how this works. None of our contacts are getting an SMS. I haven't done SMS sends using data extensions before, only lists, so I feel like I've missed something somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being opted-out of a keyword versus not subscribed to a keyword are two entirely different things. If the user has used the STOP keyword to opt-out of `KEYWORD` they will not receive any SMS texts from that shortcode. They will need to double-opt into `KEYWORD` again.

If you're sending to subscribers who have already opt-ed out, they have an unsubscribed/opted-out status and you can't send them SMS texts until they double-opt back in.

If you're sending to subscribers who have not subscribed, you must have their permission to send that SMS text to confirm if they want to subscribe.

Also you didn't specify if you were sending to a data extension as the entry source of the journey. You also have to make sure that the phone field is in that data extension with the correct datatype.

**Subscribe all contacts to a keyword** will automatically add the contacts to the All Contacts list in Mobile Connect.

The contacts with Mobile Numbers that enter journey will never get sent an SMS text unless the Mobile number already exists in All Contacts in Mobile Connect via the method above or imported to All Contacts by file import.

But as mentioned above, if they are opted-out, they will not receive any SMS texts.

Mobile Connect documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_mobileconnect.htm&type=5

CTIA Best Practices: https://www.ctia.org/positions/documents/ctia-messaging-principles-and-best-practices

Comment: Is there a way that we use Journey to resub these opted-out subscribers? I would like to do it without importing these subscribers again through an automation.